# Colorbar colors in viewer do not match pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I am using pdf plot to create a colorbar.
The result does not match up in the TexStudio viewer and the pdf file. 
(below: left TexStudio preview, right pdf output)

[image: TexStudio preview] [image: pdf output]

My code:

```
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%colorbar sampled,colorbar style={samples=200},
        %colormap access=piecewise constant,
        colormap/viridis,xmin=0, xmax=3,ymin=-2.5,ymax=5, width=1.1\textwidth,
        height=0.75\textwidth,white, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, colorbar
        ,colorbar style={height=0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis width}}]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Try what happens if you remove the `[cmyk]` option of xcolor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminal output and the log file for the original code show the following message (PGF/TikZ 3.0.1a):

```
Package pgfplots Warning: colorbar remark: The colormap 'viridis' has a CMYK co
lorspace which is not (yet) supported by PGF. I switched colorbar styles automa
tically to the visually equivalent 'colorbar sampled={surf,shader=interp}' to g
enerate a proper CMYK colorbar. This has less support in some previewers. Use \
pgfplotscolorbarCMYKworkaroundfalse to disable this improvement. [This message 
won't be replicated for 'viridis'] on input line 15.
```

Following the suggestion given there to add `\pgfplotscolorbarCMYKworkaroundfalse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotscolorbarCMYKworkaroundfalse

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%colorbar sampled,colorbar style={samples=200},
        %colormap access=piecewise constant,
        colormap/viridis,xmin=0, xmax=3,ymin=-2.5,ymax=5, width=1.1\textwidth,
        height=0.75\textwidth,white, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, colorbar
        ,colorbar style={height=0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis width}}]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This leads to the following message in the log:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: I am about to convert colormap 'viridis' from cmyk to
 rgb (which might be lossy). Perhaps the choice 'colorbar sampled={surf,shader=
interp}' yields better results since it supports cmyk. on input line 16.
```

However the output is as desired in Evince:

[image]

Note that CMYK support in PGF was improved in version 3.1.3, so an upgrade could already be sufficient to solve your issue.

Comment: thank you, an upgrade helped!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working whit Windows 10, MikTeX compiler and TeXstudio GUI.
And this is my results.

Note that I have only add `\documentclass[]{article}` in the headers.

Please, tell us more about your enviroment about LaTeX and OS. ;-)

Thankyou and bye,
Jack

[image: Your code and result]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am quite desperate at this point.
My original file adds ```documentclass[a4paper,cleardoubleempty, 11pt, twoside]{report}```. I use Ubuntu 18.10, MikTeX compiler and TeXStudio.

Comment: So, if your compiler is MikTeXm and your GUI is TeXStudio, you *should* the same things that I see.